# Суммирование поставок по определенному товару, пока не будет достигнут лимит

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Есть таблица с поставками товаров. Товар/Количество/Дата. Нужно получить дату, когда был достигнут объем поставки по заданному товару.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При таких ограничениях (без доп. столбцов и формула в одной ячейке) приходится применять летучую `СМЕЩ`:

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ИНДЕКС(C2:C15;ПОИСКПОЗ(1=1;СУММЕСЛИ(СМЕЩ(A2;;;СТРОКА(2:15)-1);F1;СМЕЩ(B2;;;СТРОКА(2:15)-1))>=F2;));"Порог не достигнут")
```

Формула массива, вводится тремя клавишами `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

Если результат (дата) используется для дальнейших вычислений, текст лучше заменить нулем.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!!!